# How do I set up No-IP as a proper service?

Tags: services, dynamic-ip

There is an example service shell script in the download, but it seems limited and relies on `killproc` which doesn't exist by default on Ubuntu 16 LTS.

Answer (score 19):

Ubuntu 16 LTS uses `systemd` as the init system. This assumes you have already downloaded & installed the `noip2` update client.

1. Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/noip2.service` as follows:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=No-Ip Dynamic DNS Update Service
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   Type=forking
   ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/noip2

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. Reload the init daemon:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
3. Enable the service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable noip2
   ```
4. Start the service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start noip2
   ```

Derived from [this readme](https://github.com/jeroendoggen/scripts-tools-misc/tree/master/noip2)

Answer (score 5):

I used the [`sysvinit` guide from Jonas Friedmann](https://blog.frd.mn/how-to-set-up-proper-startstop-services-ubuntu-debian-mac-windows/#debian-and-ubuntu-sysvinit-).

1. Download and untar the No-IP DUC:
   `wget https://www.noip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz`
   `tar -xf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz --exclude='._*'` (excludes Mac dotfiles)
2. Make and install it:
   `cd noip-x.y` (where *x.y* is version)
   `make` (errors here may mean you're missing compilation packages)
   `sudo make install`
3. Create the file `/etc/init.d/noip` with these contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides:          noip
   # Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $syslog
   # Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $syslog
   # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
   # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
   # Short-Description: no-ip DUC
   # Description:       Update DNS for dynamic IP on noip.com
   ### END INIT INFO

   NAME="noip"
   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
   APPDIR="/"
   APPBIN="/usr/local/bin/noip2"
   PIDFILE="/var/run/${NAME}-customservice.pid"

   # Include functions 
   set -e
   . /lib/lsb/init-functions

   start() {
       printf "Starting '$NAME'... "
       start-stop-daemon --start --background --make-pidfile --pidfile "$PIDFILE" --chdir "$APPDIR" --exec "$APPBIN" || true
       printf "done\n"
   }

   #We need this function to ensure the whole process tree will be killed
   killtree() {
       local _pid=$1
       local _sig=${2-TERM}
       for _child in $(ps -o pid --no-headers --ppid ${_pid}); do
           killtree ${_child} ${_sig}
       done
       kill -${_sig} ${_pid}
   }

   stop() {
       printf "Stopping '$NAME'... "
       [ -z `cat "$PIDFILE" 2>/dev/null` ] || \
           while test -d /proc/$(cat "$PIDFILE"); do
               killtree $(cat "$PIDFILE") 15
               sleep 0.5
           done 
       [ -z `cat "$PIDFILE" 2>/dev/null` ] || rm "$PIDFILE"
       printf "done\n"
   }

   status() {
       "$APPBIN" -S
   }

   configure() {
       "$APPBIN" -C
   }

   case "$1" in
       start)
           start
           ;;
       stop)
           stop
           ;;
       restart)
           stop
           start
           ;;
       status)
           status
           ;;
       configure)
           configure
           ;;
       *)
           echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|status|configure}" >&2
           exit 1
           ;;
   esac

   exit 0
   ```

   (I used `sudo vim /etc/init.d/noip`.)
4. Make it executable:
   `sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/noip`
5. Enable it:
   `sudo update-rc.d noip defaults`
6. Configure it:
   `sudo service noip configure`
7. Start it:
   `sudo service noip start`
8. Check it:
   `sudo service noip status`

Feedback is welcome.

Comment: For the record, I should have done it as a *systemd* service.