# Ubuntu 20.04 - noip client

Tags: 20.04, dyndns

Trying to get the noip client to work but having issues, started following this [link](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/):

Then did the first answer [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089704/cant-get-service-noip2-to-start-on-boot)

But when I now do:
`sudo systemctl status noip2.service`

I get the following error:

```
noip2.service - noip2 service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/noip2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Sun 2020-11-22 19:39:44 CET; 8s ago
    Process: 43373 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/noip2 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 22 19:39:44 prutt systemd[1]: noip2.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 22 19:39:44 prutt systemd[1]: Stopped noip2 service.
Nov 22 19:39:44 prutt systemd[1]: noip2.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 22 19:39:44 prutt systemd[1]: noip2.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Nov 22 19:39:44 prutt systemd[1]: Failed to start noip2 service.
```

Any ideas?