# How can I log in and run a bash file at boot?

Tags: server, 20.04, bash

I got myself a minecraft server that turns on and off on specific hours but I don't want to type the commands every time it should start playing and let it run those commands after boot. I found an old askubuntu thread (for 12.04) where this is handled and let it run as root. But for security reasons, I don't want it to run as root. I would like to still be able to type in commands to like stop the server, so it cannot run my bash script somewhere hidden.

Comment: Read `man 5 crontab`, and use the special `@reboot` date field.

Comment: Sounds like you need an ordinary [startup](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089789/986805) script, this should work as a template, with `Group=`, `User=` [directive](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/systemd.exec.5.html) you may specify different user, group (I would also recommend `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system` instead of `/etc/systemd/system`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use a crontab entry for your user.

The command to run a command att boot is "@reboot".

Example of crontab entry:

```
@reboot   cd /home && sh ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: And... how can I set that crontab entry?

Comment: Run the command `crontab -e`

Comment: thanks, ill try that tomorrow

Comment: Storing scripts in `/home` is not common (nor recommended). It's also preferable to use the full path to your command. Specifying the shell on the command line `/bin/sh script.sh` will pass the *interpret directive* `#!` as a regular comment instead of *specified* interpreter. And if they differ may lead to feature inconsistency.

Comment: My script is also not in home, it's in /home/myUserName/survival

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, but this gives me an idea of what i'm searching for. Thanks

Comment: Update, I did some more research and it seems I used the command wrong...

Answer (score 0):

To automatically run a command every time the system boots:

- Search "Startup Applications" in the dash and open it.
- Click add. For the name put "Start Minecraft Server" and under "command" put your command used to start your Minecraft server.
- Press add and now the script should run on restart/startup.

Enjoy!

Comment: If the Ubuntu installation used the server version instead of the desktop version, this will not possible as there's no way to access a GUI program. Although, for cases like these I would recommend a systemd unit as suggested by @bac0n comment's above. As you will most likely want easier control to stop and restart such software.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I just thought I would share this method as a less programming-savy alternative.

Comment: I didn't mean it as the answer is wrong, to complain or anything of the sort. Sorry if it sounded like that! The answer is absolutely fine. But I just wanted to mention it as a "disclaimer" for this specific case.

Comment: @Dan All good, It was a good point I hadn't considered, thankyou! :)

Comment: I like this idea, but I can't access a GUI.